# How to change KeystoneJS v6 database from default SQLite to MySQL

Tags: javascript, keystonejs

By default, when I installed KeystoneJS v6 headless CMS, it's connected to SQLite database.

If I try to change provider to MySQL, in file `keystone.ts` I first replace provider to `'mysql'` and url to `mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/keystone`.

Then I run command `npx keystone-next migrate`, but I get error

> 'keystone-next@*' is not in this registry

So, it seems it tries to install something instead of migrating

Answer (score 0):

`keystone-next/keystone` is deprecated and was migrated to `@keystone-6/core`.

Link to the old npm package: [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@keystone-next/keystone)

Link to the new npm package: [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@keystone-6/core)

Note that if you have keystone installed in the project, you can use `npx keystone prisma migrate`.